# Select from two indexing lists, create list of new objects

Tags: c#, linq, list, select

I have two Lists: `List<Vertex> points`, holding vertices (x,y) and a list `List<Triangles> triangles`, holding the nodes (a,b,c) of a triangle. Thus, a,b,c are indeces of points that define a triangle.

I would now like to easily calculate on these. E.g. I would like to get all vectors form point a to point b for every triangle:

```
list<vector> p21;
foreach triangle t p21.add(new vector(p[t.b].x-p[t.a].x, p[t.b].y-p[t.a].y));
```

but I'm sure this can be done very elegantly using linq.

Something like (not using vector but a "vertex")

```
List<Vertex> = (from triangle in triangles select a,b  and from point in points select new { pi[b].x-pi[a], pi[b].x-pi[a] };
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I assume you want the triangles to be unique?

Comment: triangles should unique... I check for this in advance (delaunay triangulation). Is something like

List<Vertex> bc =  (from triangle in triangles select new Vertex( points[triangle.b].x - points[triangle.c].x, points[triangle.b].x - points[triangle.c].y)).ToList()

valid or is there a better/faster option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it. It's quite self-describing, and as simple as possible.

```
var verticesAb = triangles
    .Select(t => new Vertex(
        points[b].x - points[a].x,
        points[b].y - points[a].y));
```

You can/should add `.ToList()` or `ToArray()` if you need a concrete collection at once.
Your version from the comment also seems OK.

Comment: perfect - thanks. Wasn't sure whether that would perform fast enough.

Comment: @Shrizzi It's a 1:1 conversion problem - no faster way than `O(n)`.

Comment: I mean in terms of coding. I'm rather new to linq and c# so I was wondering whether a for loop or similar would be better. Thanks!

Comment: @Shrizzi Ah, this way. Yes, once you get accustomed to LINQ you will solve such tasks very fast ;)